# Java program error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing

I am lost! I am taking an online Java course and need so  assistance with this assignment.
Once the program is compile it produces a cannot find symbol error

```
Loan loan = new Loan(annualInterestRate, numberOfYears, loanAmount);
symbol:   class Loan
location: class ChangeRequest5
```

I have tried to create the class Loan with in the class ChangeRequest5 and also the method for getMonthlyPaymen. The program runs a clean and successful build and creates the user input for the interest rate, the loan term, and the loan amount but will not display the table.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

 public class ChangeRequest5 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] rateList = new Object[9];
    int i = 0;
    for (double rate = 5; rate <=6; rate += 1.0 /4)
        rateList[i++] = new Double (rate);

    Object annualInterestRateObject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null, "Select annual interest rate:" , "Mortgage Calculator" ,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, rateList, null);

    double annualInterestRate =
            ((Double)annualInterestRateObject).doubleValue();

    Object[]yearList = {new Integer(7), new Integer(15), new Integer(30)};

    Object numberOfYearsObject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null, "Select number of years:" , "Mortgage Calculator" ,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, yearList, null);
            int numberOfYears = ((Integer)numberOfYearsObject).intValue();

    String loanAmountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter loan amount, for example  200000  for $200000.00" , "Mortgage Calculator" , 
              JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    double loanAmount = Double.parseDouble(loanAmountString);


    Loan loan = new Loan(annualInterestRate, numberOfYears, loanAmount);
    double monthlyPayment = loan.getMonthlyPayment();


    String output = "Interest Rate:" + annualInterestRate + 
            "%" + "Number of Years:" + numberOfYears + " Loan Amount: $"
            + loanAmount;
    output += " Monthly Payment: " + "$" + (int)(monthlyPayment * 100) /100.0;
    output += " Totaly Payment $" + (int) (monthlyPayment * 12 * numberOfYears
            * 100) / 100.0;

    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;

    double balance = loanAmount;
    double interest;
    double principal;

    output += " Payment#\tInterest\rPrincipal\tBalance";

    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfYears * 12; i++){
      interest = (int)(monthlyInterestRate * balance * 100) / 100.0;
      principal = (int)((monthlyPayment - interest) * 100) / 100.0;
      balance = (int)((balance - principal) * 100) / 100.0;

      output += i + "\t" + interest + "\t" + principal + "\t" + balance;
    }

    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(output));
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 200));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jsp,
        "Mortgage Calculator" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you've defined a class called `Loan`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a file `Loan.java` defining a class `Loan` in the same package? If it's in the same package it should work.

[image]

If it's in a different package, you need to import it in your other .java file:

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import package2.Loan;

 public class ChangeRequest5 {
```

Comment: I tried that and received and error as well :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
 at Loan.<init>(Loan.java:13)
 at ChangeRequest5.main(ChangeRequest5.java:38)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
 So I reverted back to the original code to see it anyone could tell me where I went wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an import statement for 'Loan' as well unless it's in the same package

Comment: Maybe.  But if Loan is also declared in the default package, you don't.